# can atx power supply the intel nuc and egpu

Tags: power-supply, 12v, atx

So I want to power my Nuc (mini-pc) with ATX psu and the reason is I built my own egpu(external graphic card) and i would like to throw the nuc in there powered by the same psu that runs the egpu which makes it a full small size gaming pc somewhat.

***the nuc needs= 19v maximum 10a maximum 120w***

atx psu have 12v output so i thought i can use a step up to push it to 19v and hook that to the nuc something like this [https://www.amazon.com/DC-DC-module-152Wmax-supply-converter/dp/B00M3SR51Y/ref=pd_lpo_107_img_0/134-5039755-4302764?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00M3SR51Y&pd_rd_r=76357fcd-882e-4ff7-a35a-0c1838a5debf&pd_rd_w=vjM7d&pd_rd_wg=5tR29&pf_rd_p=7b36d496-f366-4631-94d3-61b87b52511b&pf_rd_r=PGYVCS1MXBF0NDW007ZJ&psc=1&refRID=PGYVCS1MXBF0NDW007ZJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M3SR51Y)

However how can i get that 12v out of the psu??? do i use the 24pin or the 4 pin and which wire do i need to use??

I found a lot of videos on youtube to change the Whole atx psu into 12v dc output (*but they completely use the whole cables by cutting all the pins and make it into dc output which means i can not use it anymore to connect egpu to it*) like this https://youtu.be/M4TFVhCg6sk

Comment: Probably a better fit for SuperUser as this question is on how to use an ATX power supply.

Comment: I think super user would reject it in it's current state, I'll close it for now and if more details are added it could be moved. Really need to see good formatting and possibly a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

> However how can i get that 12v out of the psu??? do i use the 24pin or
> the 4 pin and which wire do i need to use??

you have to turn the power supply on to use any output. usually, the procedure is:

1. (*optional*) use a simple circuit to monitor `PG(power_good)` signal. you can power this monitoring circuit by using an *always on* supply pin provided on the 24pin socket. it's named `5VSB` (5V stand-by). when the PG signal get's high, the power supply is ready and the voltages are stable.
2. use the `PS_ON` pin to turn the power supply on by setting it to a LOW level (GND). after this, all power rails are activated.
3. provide a proper `load` for power supply to keep it on. many power supplies turn off automatically if they don't see any load connected. for your purpose, you can skip this step too.

[image]